# jqvery работа метода replaseWith

Tags: jquery

```js
$("h2").each(function() { // Заменить<h2> на <h1>,
var h2 = $(this); // сохранивсодержимое
h2.replaceWith("<h1>" + h2.html() + "</h1>");
});
```

как происходит удаление элемента h2 ? Мне кажется в результате должно получиться h2h1 содержимое h1h2

Comment: а если по-человечески сформулировать?

Comment: В документации всё написано понятно и с примерами http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: Исходники наверно тоже можно понять, хотя мне лень над ними думать https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0aa832afec04215ed5e14b1cc5fc287ad7939792/src/manipulation.js#L438-L454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот наглядно видно как меняет. Оно меняет тот контейнер с содержимым который вы задали.

```js
$("h2").each(function() { // Заменить<h2> на <h1>,
  var h2 = $(this); // сохранивсодержимое
  h2.replaceWith("<h1>" + h2.html() + "</h1>");
});
```

```css
h2{color: red;}
span{color: blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>h22222<span>spannnn</span>h222</h2>
```

Подробно описано [тут](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).